# Business Loan in British Colombia

Tags: working-visas, canada, loan

I have a work visa in Canada. What if, I buy a house on mortgage, will the bank give me loan for business on the papers of that house?

Comment: Welcome to expatriates.SE.  I don't think that this is on topic here but if you have sufficient equity in the property you may be able to take a loan against it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Karlson. but let me re do the question here. I am just getting a mortgage next month for like 400,000. After that will i be able to take a business loan for 300,000 on that house?

Comment: They will only grant a loan against your equity in the house. You would have to have invested 300k (and likely more) into the purchase, thus the house would have to be worth at least 700k.

Comment: You could ask on http://money.stackexchange.org/

Comment: @Gala there may be differences in load policies for permanent residents and those on temporary visas. For example, most building societies in the UK won't give home mortgages to people without indefinite leave to remain.

Comment: @Gala [money.stackexchange.com](http://money.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @StrongBad Maybe but the question is a bit more general. I didn't vote either way but if it's closed or does not attract sufficient attention here, I thought that knowing about the other might be useful to the OP.

Comment: @StrongBad There are usually differences between permanent residents and temporary visas in terms of risk and thus the rate that banks will charge but collateral is collateral.

Comment: What visa are you on, and what is your citizenship? Might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on so many more factors than your visa and house value. Each bank has their own underwriters and policies on this.

The only way you're going to definitively be able to answer this is to discuss with a mortgage broker in BC, or with one of the loan managers at one of the banks.